# Search an object for associated data

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have an object like so:

```
var products = {"products":[
    {"productID":"32652", "name":"Playstation 4", "price":"109.99"},
    {"productID":"24164", "name":"Xbox", "price":"129.99"}
]};
```

I need to search with the variable `productID` and find the associated `name` and `price`

My searches have just led me off track with things like `.closest` which is for the DOM not for an object.

How can I search the object for the `productID` var and find the associated data?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find an object by property value in an array of JavaScript objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364150/find-an-object-by-property-value-in-an-array-of-javascript-objects)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```
var foundProduct = products.products.find(x => x.productId === "12345")
if (foundProduct) { // foundProduct can be undefined. 
    var foundName = foundProduct.name
    var foundPrice = foundProduct.price
} else { /* handle not found */ }
```

If you are in a context that doesn't support Array.find yet, you can use .filter instead which is more commonly implemented.

```
var foundProduct = products.products.filter(x => x.productId === "12345")[0]
if (foundProduct) { // foundProduct can be undefined. 
    var foundName = foundProduct.name
    var foundPrice = foundProduct.price
} else { /* handle not found */ }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
var result = products.products.filter(function(obj) {
  return obj.name == "Xbox";
})[0];
```

Note that `.filter` will return an array. If you just need the first match then this will work for you. In case you need all the results then just remove the `[0]`

Comment: Hey, I'm a bit confused by this answer because you have hardcoded "Xbox" in place. I am trying to find out that data, so how can I have it hardcoded into the function?

Comment: @user1486133 the hardcoded "Xbox" can be any variable you want. It can be anything this is just an example of how it is done

Answer (score 0):

```
var products = {"products":[
   {"productID":"32652", "name":"Playstation 4", "price":"109.99"},
   {"productID":"24164", "name":"Xbox", "price":"129.99"}
]};

function findProduct(product) { 
   return product.productID === '24164';
}

console.log(products.products.find(findProduct)); //{productID: "24164", name: "Xbox", price: "129.99"}
```

Comment: The find method executes the callback function (findProduct) once for each element present in the array until it finds one where callback returns a true value. 
If such an element is found, find immediately returns the value of that element. Otherwise, find returns undefined.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(products.products.find(function(p) {return p.productID === '24164'}));
```